# Limit the CPU usage of scripts run with cron

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm having issue with CPU usage overload. I have a paid hosting with Hostinger, and for two times in a row, I got automatic suspension for "CPU limit exceeded" (if I remember well, it basically said that my website exceeded the CPU time limit too many times).

As I'm probably the only visitor of my website (still building it), I guess this is because of the scripts that are running with CRON. It's weird because they seemed to cause no problem for quite some time, and then all of a sudden they do.

As I am a noob (I'm learning php by myself on the job), I'm sure I'm making inefficient things.

1. First script reads the content of a few XML files from external websites (RSS feeds), and inserts any new links in my database (with a field crawl_status = 0)
2. Second script selects links in my database that have a crawl_status = 0 (with a limit of 10 items max each time), crawls the content of those links (using CURL), copies some of this data to my database (and sets crawl_status = 1 so that the links are only crawled once)
3. Third script asks facebook API for the number of shares for 20 of the links, and writes the results in the database.

All three scripts are run every minute with cron.

My question is : are there more efficient ways to do what I do, and if so, how ? (For instance, I don't know, maybe not going with cron running every minute but using another way)

Comment: How long do the scripts each take to run?

Comment: Contact your provider about the error message. Concerning your approach: Hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: well the obvious answer is to run the cron every 10 minutes / hour / day /week etc. The other obvious answer is to shell out $5 a month for a cheapo vps (Digital Ocean for example) and thus avoid the issue all together

Comment: You could also probably make the code more efficient, but as you havent posted any, theres no way to help with that.

Comment: Crawling external sites can take rather long and you're spawning three new processes every minute. I bet you manage to get several instances of the same scripts running simultaneously.